# Using Restangular with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, restangular

I am trying to convert my RestAngular Services to Typescript. I occured a problem with the configuration part, that you can do with restangular.

Im a bit confused how i can achieve the same functionality with a typescript class.

My AngularJS Code

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp.ui.services')
    .factory('statData', statData);

statData.$inject = ['Restangular', '$angularCacheFactory'];

/* @ngInject */
function statData(Restangular, $angularCacheFactory) {
    var statDataCache = $angularCacheFactory('statDataCache');
    statDataCache .setOptions({
                               capacity: 10,
                               recycleFreq: 60000,
                               cacheFlushInterval: 3600000,
                               deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
                               storageMode: 'localStorage'
                           });

    return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: statDataCache });
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('data/');
    });
}
})();
```

TypeScript

```
 export class StatDataService{

    static $inject = ['Restangular', '$angularCacheFactory'];
    private _statDataCache: any;

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor(public restNg: ng.IRestangularService, public $angularCacheFactory: ng.ICacheFactoryService) {
        this._statDataCache = $angularCacheFactory('statDataCache');
        this._statDataCache.setOptions({
                                   capacity: 10,
                                   recycleFreq: 60000,
                                   cacheFlushInterval: 3600000,
                                   deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
                                   storageMode: 'localStorage'
                               });
    }
}
```

The Problem is this specific part

```
  return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: statDataCache });
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('data/');
    });
```

How can i include this into my TypeScript class?

Comment: And what is the output of your TypeScript compiler? Or what is the problem for that matter?

Comment: My Problem is I don't know how i can write the bottom Part with a TypeScript Class, because of the `return`

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/restangular/restangular.d.ts#L101 - it seems that the return type is `IService`. If you don't know and don't have time to solve the issue, you can just use `any`.

Comment: I want that the class creates the cache and is returning the configured restangular service, like in my js file.
I could solve it with a factory method, but i wanted to know if there are other ideas or attempts to solve my question